# SQL: replace some values of a table with results from a predetermined query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can the following tasks be done entirely in an SQL script?

My database holds recipes. What I want to do is pull as subsection of the ingredient lines. Which is no problem. I can pull back  something like this:

```
RECIPE LINE INGREDIENT DESC

Cake1  1    Sugar      Sugar
Cake1  2    CakeMix    PreMix for a Cake
Cake1  3    Water      Water
```

However in this example Line 2 is actually recipe itself called CakeMix and is being used as an ingredient in Cake1.
CakeMix appears somewhere else in the same table as its own recipe as shown below for example:

```
RECIPE   LINE INGREDIENT DESC
CakeMix   1   Mix1       Line one of Mix
CakeMix   2   Mix2       Line two of Mix
```

So what I would like is some sort of **IF Statement** that searches the results of the top table for a Key word say "PreMix" and would then puts that recipe ID into another select statement to pull out the second table and combines it into the following:

```
RECIPE   LINE INGREDIENT DESC

Cake1     1    Sugar      Sugar
CakeMix   1   Mix1       Line one of Mix
CakeMix   2   Mix2       Line two of Mix
Cake1     3    Water      Water
```

Is there a way of doing this purely in SQL?

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.? Take a look at how bill-of-materials problem has been solved: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2009/11/06/bill-of-materials-the-basics.aspx.

Comment: Hi Im using Microsft SQL Server Management Studio 2012. 
Brilliant Ill check that out now. Thanks.

Comment: Aha, SSMS 2012 is your client. Your server is SQL Server. You might have to tweak your tables a little bit with in-table parent-child relationship for bill-of-materials-like query to work for you. You can even google up Bill of Material SQL Server to see different variations of the query

Comment: Unfortunately the tables cant really change as mutiple systems read from them so the structure cant really be altered but Il definately check that out. thanks

Comment: If you have MS Sql Server you can do it using a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a number of ways. The two that come to mind first are CTEs and the use of variables in TSql.

**CTE Method**

```
WITH cteFirstLine(RecipeID)
AS
(
    SELECT RecipeID FROM TblMixes WHERE DESC LIKE 'Premix%'
) 
SELECT * FROM TblRecipes r
    JOIN cteFirstLine f ON f.RecipeID=r.RecipeID
```

**Variable in TSQL**

```
DECLARE @recipeID INT

SELECT @recipeID=RecipeID FROM TblMixes WHERE DESC LIKE 'Premix%' AND Recipe = 'Cake1'

SELECT * FROM TblRecipes WHERE RecipeID=@recipeID
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks very much I'll give them a go there now.